# how source and bootm commands are enabled in u-boot?

Tags: c, linux, u-boot

Below is the part of file common/Makefile in U-Boot code.

```
obj-$(CONFIG_SOURCE) += cmd_source.o
obj-$(CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE) += cmd_source.o
```

I have gone through the U-Boot code but could not find these two macros defined anywhere. However, this command is available in U-Boot at runtime.
Where is this macro defined.?

Same is with `bootm` command, It is also available at run time but I'm not able to find where the macro is defined. If someone is aware about it please let me know.

Comment: I have `cmd_source.c` inside `common` folder. I'm using `Yocto` for `i.mx6`

Comment: Yes, I have too. but to compile that file, CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE should be defined somewhere, My question is where that is defined?

Comment: `include/configs/your_board_support.h`

Comment: It is not there that is why i asked here.

Comment: I'm not getting you. E.g: for `at91 Atmlel SoC` you can see it into `/include/configs/at91sam9rlek.h`. BTW using your console, inside `configs` folder, type:  `grep -rnw --color . -e "CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE"`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on build-configuration system of **your** u-boot.

1. If it's a Pre-kconfig Configuration System [1], these macros (or location/files where these macros are defined) can be found at one of these possible locations:

   - include/config.mk
   - include/config.h
   - arch/${ARCH}/include/asm/arc
   - boards.cfg

After make, it's value can be found in autoconf.mk.
For example, here's a result of grep in on my 'pre-kconfig' u-boot directory (board names removed):

```
    /u-boot-dir$ egrep -rnsH "CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE|CONFIG_SOURCE" *
    //snip...

    ./include/autoconf.mk:3:CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE=y
    ./include/config_cmd_default.h:49:#define CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE /*
    ./include/configs/board1.h:109:#undef CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE
    ./include/configs/board2_common.h:135:#define CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE
    ./include/config_cmd_all.h:32:#define CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE /* "source" command support */

    //snap...
    /u-boot-dir$
```

2. If it's a KConfig based configuration system [1], the the definitions can be found in `configs/<board>_defconfig` files.
   For example, here's a result of grep from latest u-boot source:

```
    $ git clone git://git.denx.de/u-boot.git
    Cloning into 'u-boot'...
    Resolving deltas: 100% (305309/305309), done.
    $ cd u-boot/
    /u-boot$ egrep -rnsH "CMD_SOURCE"
    //snip...

    cmd/source.c:145:#if defined(CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE)
    cmd/Makefile:20:obj-$(CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE) += source.o
    cmd/Kconfig:384:config CMD_SOURCE
    configs/at91sam9g10ek_dataflash_cs3_defconfig:11:# CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE is not set
    configs/vct_premium_small_defconfig:13:# CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE is not set
    configs/ap_sh4a_4a_defconfig:17:# CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE is not set
    configs/at91sam9g20ek_dataflash_cs0_defconfig:11:# CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE is not set

    //snap...
    /u-boot$
```

---

reference
[1]: page-12 and 13 of http://www.denx.de/wiki/pub/U-Boot/MiniSummitELCE2014/uboot2014_kconfig.pdf